# Conditional convergence of a power series on the $z \in \mathbb{C}$ for which $|z|=\rho$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Consider the following complex power series 
$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{z^n}{n} \,\,\,\,\,\,\, z \in \mathbb{C}$$

It surely converges conditionally for $z=-1$ (for alternating series test) and for $z=1$ it diverges (it is the harmonic series).

My question is: how can one show that the power series converges conditionally for **any** $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|=1$ (except for $z=1$)?

Comment: The complex version of [Abel's test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_test) will work for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the [**Dirichlet's test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) to prove the desired result: with $a_n=\frac1n$ and $b_n=e^{in\theta}$ we verify that

- $(a_n)$ is decreasing to 0
- $\sum_{n=1}^N b_n$ is bounded

so the series $\sum a_nb_n$ is convergent.